# How to query a struct in BigQuery where two key: value pairs matter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data like this:

```
date, event.key, event.values
1   ,     color,         blue
           size,          big
2   ,     color,       yellow
           size,          big
3   ,     color,       yellow
           size,        small
```

And want to filter rows which contain such key:value pairs: color=blue and size=big. So only this one row remains:

```
date, event.key, event.values
1   ,     color,         blue
           size,          big
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unnest()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(t.event) e
              where e.key = 'color' and e.value = 'blue'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from unnest(t.event) e
              where e.key = 'size' and e.value = 'big'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select *,
from `project.dataset.table` t
where (
    select count(*) = 2 from t.event
    where (key, values) in (('color', 'blue'), ('size', 'big'))
  )
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]